# Check for digits in unknown location of black rectangle

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a picture of a washing machine and a dryer that will be taken live from a webcam on a Raspberry Pi. It'll look like this, except there will be two almost identical washers:

[image: Image of a washer and dryer]

I want to check if the black rectangle has any visible digits (they emit a white or light green). Its position may change, so I don't want to just crop and check the same spot.

```
//I'll upload some code of what I have tried so far soon.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a code sample?

Comment: A code sample of what?

Comment: Of what you tried so far

Comment: I can't find it now but I did try finding the contours, but I'm not sure on what to do with that. I've messed with color detect and looked around extensively, but as I've said before I'm new to opencv so I haven't crafted something together because ultimately I don't know what method to use and some advice on functions to use for that.

Comment: Sounds good. Have you considered something more simple? For example, printing a number on a plain paper and capturing the value, and then start to something bigger? I'd recommend you start with this: http://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/basic-ocr-in-opencv/

Comment: That would work. I just need to find a way to extract that square, or I assume I would get worse results. I could just crop it, but that would be susceptible to change which I'm trying to avoid.